# SQL Select Data Retrieval with Local Variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write an SQL statement that has some cascading conditional logic in it.  I have several fields that need to be returned but their values are conditional on previously determined fields.  For example, buysell_flag is dependent on the spotfwd_flag value and counter_amt and given_amt are dependent on the buysell_flag value, and so on.

I found out quickly that I cannot combine a data retrieval query and a variable assigning query in the same space, so I tried all sorts of things but couldn't return the data I wanted to.  This is a template for clients, who will be editing this SQL and pasting it into a program.  It will not always be the same, so I can't handle the logic in the program or in a stored proc or UDF.  I've tried to use a table, but when inserting that and selecting stuff to it, I ran into the same problems.  You can see my attempts below, but if it can't be done, please let me know - otherwise, I'm open to any and all suggestions!  Thanks!

```
    DECLARE @trans_type nvarchar(255), @trade_date nvarchar(255), @settle_date nvarchar(255), 
@order_id nvarchar(255), @oaexecbroker nvarchar(255), @exec_broker nvarchar(255),
@ostatus nvarchar(255), @trade_id nvarchar(255), @reference_price nvarchar(255), 
@given_ccy nvarchar(255), @spotfwd_flag nvarchar(255), @buysell_flag nvarchar(255),
@counter_ccy nvarchar(255), @counter_amt nvarchar(255), @given_amt nvarchar(255),
@oacct_cd nvarchar(255)

SELECT 
@trans_type = o.trans_type,
@settle_date = o.settle_date,
@order_id = o.order_id,
@oaexecbroker = oa.exec_broker,
@exec_broker = o.exec_broker,
@ostatus = o.status,
@trade_id = oa.trade_id,
@reference_price = o.exec_price,
@given_ccy = o.target_crrncy,

--o.trans_type    AS trans_type, 
--  o.trade_date    AS trade_date, 
--  o.settle_date   AS settle_date, 
--  o.order_id      AS order_id, 
--  oa.exec_broker  AS oaexecbroker, 
--  o.exec_broker   AS exec_broker, 
--  o.status        AS ostatus, 
--  oa.trade_id     AS trade_id, 
--  o.exec_price    AS reference_price, 
--  o.target_crrncy as given_ccy, 
    -- for spot/fwd

    @spotfwd_flag = CASE 
        WHEN LEFT(o.inv_class_cd,1) = 'F' THEN ('FWD')
        WHEN LEFT(o.inv_class_cd,2) = 'CU' THEN ('SPOT')
    ELSE 'SPOT'
    END, -- must be spot or fwd
    --for buysell   

    @buysell_flag = CASE
        WHEN @spotfwd_flag = 'FWD' THEN 
            CASE
                WHEN o.target_crrncy = o.to_crrncy THEN 'BUY'
                ELSE 'SELL'
            END
    ELSE
        CASE 
            WHEN o.trans_type = 'BUYL' THEN 'BUY'
            ELSE 'SELL'
        END
    END, -- must be buy or sell

    @counter_amt = CASE 
        WHEN @buysell_flag = 'BUY' Then oa.exec_amt
        ELSE oa.exec_qty
    END,

    @given_amt = CASE
        WHEN @buysell_flag = 'SELL' THEN oa.exec_amt
        ELSE oa.exec_qty
    END, 

    @counter_ccy = CASE 
        WHEN o.target_crrncy = o.to_crrncy THEN o.from_crrncy
        ELSE o.to_crrncy
    END,

    @oacct_cd = CASE 
        WHEN f.udf_char6 = 'Y' THEN (oa.acct_cd + oa.custodian)
        ELSE oa.acct_cd 
    END 
FROM   ts_order_alloc oa 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ts_order o 
    ON oa.order_id = o.order_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cs_fund f 
    ON oa.acct_cd = f.acct_cd 
--  LEFT OUTER JOIN csm_security s 
--  ON o.sec_id = s.sec_id 
--WHERE  s.sec_typ_cd IN ( 'CFWD', 'CURR' ) 
--  AND o.status IN ( 'READY','ACCT' ) 
--  AND oa.usr_class_cd_2 = 'GTSSREADY' 

select @trans_type as trans_type,
    @trade_date    AS trade_date, 
    @settle_date   AS settle_date, 
    @order_id      AS order_id, 
    @oaexecbroker  AS oaexecbroker, 
    @exec_broker   AS exec_broker, 
    @ostatus        AS ostatus, 
    @trade_id     AS trade_id, 
    @reference_price   AS reference_price, 
    @given_ccy as given_ccy,
    @buysell_flag as buysell_flag,
    @spotfwd_flag as spotfwd_flag,
    @given_ccy as given_ccy,
    @counter_ccy as counter_ccy,
    @given_amt as given_amt,
    @counter_amt as counter_amt
```

EDIT:

I'm expecting to get rows out based on the given variables.  The reason I have so many vars is I was trying to get make it comply to the SQL error messages.

Should come out like so:

```
trans_type  trade_date  settle_date order_id    oaexecbroker    exec_broker ostatus trade_id    reference_price given_ccy   buysell_flag    spotfwd_flag    given_ccy   counter_ccy given_amt   counter_amt
BUYL    NULL    2010-04-06 00:00:00.000 1442084139  3PCITI  3PCITI  Ready   1389278710  1.50705 GBP BUY SPOT    GBP USD 604292  910699
```

Comment: What is the limit for local variables? God you have a lot... two things will help you here by posting (updating question with) 1. Table schema with some sample data 2. expected results...

Comment: Thanks, I removed some and added the expected results.  Table schema is waaaaay to big to post.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? I don't understand if you want to return a rowset with data, or a set of variables. Since your problem seems to be about the general concept, not this particular query, can you provide a minimal, artificial example with dummy data that illustrates your problem? It doesn't have to have anything to do with your real tables or data.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this problem correctly, what you need to do is encapsulate the logic of the calculations to use the results of those calculations later on.

Depending on the inputs of the calculations, there are many different ways of going about doing this.

- If the logic only involves values within a single *row* in a single table, you could define a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186241.aspx) to encapsulate the logic. How this works is when you `SELECT` the value of the computed column, the calculation is done automatically. This method is suitable when you need to reuse the same logic very frequently, as this is a permanent change to the table structure.
- A great way to encapsulate logic is within a view. This is kind of like a persisted column, except the results could combine data from multiple tables. Since a view can only encompass a single `SELECT` statement, you can combine it with any of the other methods presented here.
- Derived tables. That sounds fancy, but the concept is very simple: use the results of a `SELECT` statement as the input of another `SELECT` statement. Take the following example:

  ```
  DECLARE @test table
  (
      Col1 int,
      Col2 int
  );

  -- Result query (2)    
  SELECT
      a.Col1,
      (
          CASE
              WHEN a.Col3 < a.Col1 THEN 1  -- Use the computation
              ELSE 5
          END
      ) AS Col4
      FROM
      (
          -- Derived table (1)
          SELECT
              Col1,
              Col2 + Col1 AS Col3  -- Compute
              FROM @test t1
      ) a;
  ```

  The innermost query happens first (1), and in the outer query (2), you can use the results of the inner query. Continue nesting until there are no more "layers" to the computation.
- Common table expressions (CTEs). This is similar to derived tables, but a slightly different syntax, and they give you the ability to reuse the logic multiple times in the main query. Essentially, a CTE is like a view that only exists for a single query. Here is the same example as above, using a CTE instead of a derived table:

  ```
  DECLARE @test table
  (
      Col1 int,
      Col2 int
  );

  WITH a AS
  (
      -- CTE (1)
      SELECT
          Col1,
          Col2 + Col1 AS Col3  -- Compute
          FROM @test t1
  )
      -- Result query (2)    
      SELECT
          a.Col1,
          (
              CASE
                  WHEN a.Col3 < a.Col1 THEN 1  -- Use the computation
                  ELSE 5
              END
          ) AS Col4
          FROM a;
  ```

For the query you posted, you'll need more than 2 layers, so you may need to combine some of these methods, or just used derived tables for everything. The main thing is that after applying these methods, you'll probably find there's no need to use any scalar variables!